Issue in reading delta table using spark
We have a Delta table, which keeps on updating(receives data) continuously. I read data from delta table using
df = context.spark_session.read.format("delta").load(path) 
.filter("is_processed = 0").sort("versionstamp", ascending=[True]),  this command.
df is selected as per filter. I want to process the df for my business logic.
Issue is when I process the df, df gets updated automatically as there is update in delta table ( delta table changes gets reflected in df) even if i dont perform read operation. df should remain same after read even if corresponding delta table gets updated. df should be fetched/changed only when i read/fetch it.
df should change only when read operation is performed. Changes in delta table must not be reflected automatically in the df that i want to process.

Spark isn't actually reading the data until you perform an action on the dataframe (it's the whole lazy evaluation thing). You can try executing persist on the dataframe immediately following your read statement.
